# Going to the USA and search for a job an a valid C1/D visa

Tags: air-travel, transit

I had a problem with my company so they terminated my contract. I have a valid C1/D visa. Can I still go to the USA and look for a job?

Comment: A C1/D visa is for transiting, not for looking for a job.

Comment: You should probably get a B-1 visa to enter the US to look for a job.

Answer (score 6):

No. A [C-1/D visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/crewmember-visa.html) permits you to transit the US and work on commercial sea vessels or international airlines. It is not a suitable visa for job hunting.

A [B-1 visa](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-visitors-business/b-1-temporary-business-visitor) (or [the Visa Waiver Program](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/frequently-asked-questions-about-visa-waiver-program-vwp-and-electronic-system-travel), if you're a citizen of an eligible country) would allow you to come to the US for business meetings, including a job interview. It will not, however, allow you to work in the US; any prospective employer would need to sponsor an employment visa for that purpose, which may be impossible in many circumstances. Depending on your circumstances, it may also be difficult to obtain a B-1 visa if you're unemployed, as the burden will be on you to demonstrate that you will return to your home and will not try to work illegally in the US.